# Simple Parallel Tasks with Continuation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have been reading for the 2 hours and I am still confused. Some say use StartNew, some say Task.Run some say something else. I do know that Task.Run is giving me a compile error.

I need to start multiple tasks in parallel and then when each completes successfully do a continuation task. Knowing when all are done with blocking would be helpful.

Here is what I have:

```
    public void DoSomeWork(object workItem)
    {
        var tasks = new Task<ResultArgs>[_itemList.Count];

        for (int loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < _itemList.Count; loopCnt++)
        {
            tasks[loopCnt] = new Task<ResultArgs>.Run(() =>
            {
                return _itemList[loopCnt].Analyze(workItem);
            });
            tasks[loopCnt].ContinueWith(ReportResults, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        }
    }
```

The compile says Run does not exist in Task.

Obviously, I have something run but I do not know what.

How do I get past this problem?

Comment: `Task.Run` exists only in 4.5, not in 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do with `async` methods or you can flow your items into a dataflow the following code uses `Tpl-dataflow` to process your items, passes them to your second processing step and finally await completion of processing.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace AsyncProcessing {

    [TestFixture]
    public class PipelineTests {

        [Test]
        public async Task RunPipeline() {
            var pipeline = new MyPipeline();
            var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => new WorkItem(x, x));

            foreach(var item in data) {
                await pipeline.SendAsync(item);
            }

            pipeline.Complete();
            await pipeline.Completion;

            //all processing complete            
        }
    }

    class MyPipeline {

        private BufferBlock<WorkItem> inputBuffer;
        private TransformBlock<WorkItem, WorkItem> analyzeBlock;
        private TransformBlock<WorkItem, ResultArg> reportBlock;
        private ActionBlock<ResultArg> postOutput;

        public ConcurrentBag<ResultArg> OutputBuffer { get; }
        public Task Completion { get { return postOutput.Completion; } }

        public MyPipeline() {
            OutputBuffer = new ConcurrentBag<ResultArg>();
            CreatePipeline();
            LinkPipeline();
        }

        public void Complete() {
            inputBuffer.Complete();
        }

        public async Task SendAsync(WorkItem data) {
            await inputBuffer.SendAsync(data);
        }

        public void CreatePipeline() {
            var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                BoundedCapacity = 10
            };

            inputBuffer = new BufferBlock<WorkItem>(options);

            analyzeBlock = new TransformBlock<WorkItem, WorkItem>(item => {
                //Anylyze item....
                return item;
            }, options);

            reportBlock = new TransformBlock<WorkItem, ResultArg>(item => {
                //report your results, email.. db... etc.
                return new ResultArg(item.JobId, item.WorkValue);
            }, options);

            postOutput = new ActionBlock<ResultArg>(item => {
                OutputBuffer.Add(item);
            }, options);
        }

        public void LinkPipeline() {
            var options = new DataflowLinkOptions() {
                PropagateCompletion = true,
            };

            inputBuffer.LinkTo(analyzeBlock, options);
            analyzeBlock.LinkTo(reportBlock, options);
            reportBlock.LinkTo(postOutput, options);
        }
    }

    public class WorkItem {

        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int WorkValue { get; set; }

        public WorkItem(int id, int workValue) {
            this.JobId = id;
            this.WorkValue = workValue;
        }
    }

    public class ResultArg {

        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int Result { get; set; }

        public ResultArg(int id, int result) {
            this.JobId = id;
            this.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion of async methods. I think I have it correct as the compiler is not fussing. We will find out when I start testing! I also will look into the TPL Dataflow which I had never seen before.

Comment: See the edit for a crash course in dataflow :) Also [Intro to dataflow](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html)

Comment: Thanks! More reading! Stephen's stuff is usually good and worth reading. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) loop? This is used for parallel executing tasks, it can use multiple threads and execution is faster.

However it might fail if you are doing some database related input-output operation where locking is involved. In that case I would suggest in each task keep a return type and based on return type for previous task enable the next task.

Comment: I had given Parallel.ForEach a thought but had been warned that it would not put all of my tasks on the ready to run queue. It would limit the number each time and because of near real time constraints I was concerned about throughput.

However, that does remind me that I need to worry about exceptions!

Comment: @AeroClassics `async` has similar restrictions too if it uses defalt task scheduler.

Comment: Oh fiddlesticks. That is not what I really wanted to hear but what I needed to know. Thanks!